# Jquery detect mobile browser close event

Tags: jquery

There's been voluminous discussion over the years about how to detect "close window". We need this specifically for sending analytics data (navigator.sendBeacon approach) that necessarily must occur at the very end of the user leaving the page. There's a great article at https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/ which promotes the use of a combination of VisibilityState along with pagehide in order to cover the various browsers, desktop/mobile. It's a little outdated and we found it necessary to use beforeunload as well. Here is our current code, working for the cases listed:

```
// Chrome (desktop) - refresh, navigate away
// Chrome (mobile) - background mode
// Safari (desktop) - change tab
// Safari (mobile) - background mode
// Firefox (desktop) - refresh, navigate away, change tab, close tab
// Firefox (mobile) - background mode
$(document).on('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState == 'hidden') {
        Testing();
    }
});

// Chrome (desktop) - change tab, close tab, close browser
// Safari (desktop) - refresh, close tab, close browser
// Firefox (desktop) - close browser
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    Testing();  
});

// Chrome (mobile) - refresh, navigate away
// Safari (desktop) - navigate away
// Safari (mobile) - refresh, navigate away
// Firefox (mobile) - refresh, navigate away
$(window).on('pagehide', function() {
    Testing();  
});


var executed = false; 

function Testing() {

    if (!executed) {

        executed = true;

        var fd = new FormData(); 
        fd.append("action", "testing");

        var status = navigator.sendBeacon("<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>", fd);
        console.log("sendBeacon = " + status);

    }

}
```

This is all working great, but specifically on iOS it fails to detect the case where the browser is actually fully closed. i.e. the user "swipes up" to close the entire browser (whether Chrome, Safari, or Firefox).

Is there an event to detect when a browser app is closed this way on iOS? Or if not that, an event to detect when the browser app is "slid" up slightly into the "app switcher" mode (appears this does NOT trigger background mode if/until the user actually taps out of that). It's the last/only outstanding case that would finally allow this to work!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the new IE (Safari, or as a matter of a fact, all iPhone browsers, ie. skins to Safari) ?